# Key points to ensure that a trainer is compatible with bicycle?

Tags: trainer, indoor

What should I be looking at to ensure that my bicycle and my trainer are compatible?

The current question is: I currently have a Surly Disc Trucker with 26 inch geometry, would that be compatible with the [2013 Kinetic By Kurt](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BNCA0Y)?

What things so I look at to ensure that a bicycle and a trainer are compatible with each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, not much. You need to look at the manufacturer's wheel size ratings and the hub widths allowed, along with the type of the axle (e.g. if you have a maxle, you'll need a special replacement maxle). If you're still not sure, contact the manufacturer.

If you have a standard width hub (130 to 135 mm, which you have), and 26 or 700c wheels (which you have) and a standard quick release hub (which you have), you're pretty much good to go with nearly all trainers on the market.

[Kurt Kinetic](https://kurtkinetic.com/technical-information/bike-compatibility/) has a page describing their compatibility here. If you're still not sure, either go to your LBS and try one, or contact Kurt Kinetic themselves.